# adding many polyLines in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

Is there a way to add all my poly lines at once. Doing it the way below is very slow...

At the moment, I'm doing it through a for loop as follows:

```
leafletProxy("mainMap") %>% 
          addPolylines(lng = currentGeoData[i,c("CustLon","SerCenterLon")], 
                       lat = currentGeoData[i,c("CustLat","SerCenterLat")],
                       color = "red")
```

so each time my `lng`variable is vector of length 2 and my `lat` variable is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're going through the entire column, you don't need to index with `i`:

```
leafletProxy("mainMap") %>% 
        addPolylines(lng = currentGeoData[c("CustLon","SerCenterLon")], 
                   lat = currentGeoData[c("CustLat","SerCenterLat")],
                   color = "red")
```

Comment: This drew ugly connections between the end of one and the beginning of the next line for me. How can I avoid them?